# How to hide specific list from user or a group

Tags: list, sharepoint-foundation, permissions, user-accounts

I have one list called Projects. I want to enable this list to the administrators or project managers. If any other person login to the site, that list **should not** be appear to that person. Also it should not appear in the quick launch also. I tried with target audience but not succeeded. I think that approach is wrong. How to do this? Need to write any code or shall we do by user interface it self only!!
I would feel great if any one suggest me the ways to do it.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

1. Stop inherit permissions for this list.
2. Create your own level of permission (Site Actions->Site Permissions->Permissions Levels(on ribbon)): check "view items", "view pages", "open site"("open")
3. Associate new level with the user in list permissions

Answer (score 1):

In a senario where you want to show a specific data only to a specific user or a group, whereas all the other data in the list should be visible to everyone else in the company. You can use the following approach

> 1. Create two views, one with all the all the list data that you want
>      to show to your readers in the company.
> 2. Next create another view that will conatin other columns which you
>      want to show it to a specific users.
> 3. Create a new column "Privileged User" People and Group and with
>      "Allow Multiple Selections" is Yes and "Allow Selection of" ->
>      "People Only"
> 4. Next Filter your second view where the "Privileged User" as [Me]
> 5. Lastly, Edit the list in a datasheet view and copy and paste the
>      user or group that you want to give access to in the Privileged User
>      column.

Thats it!

Taken from : [Hiding List from Users](http://spdailytips.blogspot.co.uk/2011/09/showhide-list-items-from-specific-users.html)

Hope it helped ;)

> However I done it once but for that I had to break list permissions
>   and create new permission level for groups that can view it only and
>   the other users/groups were not given new permission level :)

Comment: @yaron.... I dont want to hide only specific columns from the list. I want to hide the list to the user. Above solution is not correct one.

Comment: like I said you can break list permissions and then assign it to only people you want to show it to :)

Answer (score 1):

Break permisisons/ inheritance on the list. You do this by going to the list/library permssions/stop inhertiting permisions. Then tick the box next to the groups/people you don't want to see the list then select 'remove user permissions.' from te ribbon. That's it. If a group/user doesn't at least have read permission to a list/library then they will not see it. I.E. Will be collapsed on a page as web part with 'you don't not have permission to view this source' On the quick launch or on all site content, will be invisible.

Answer (score 0):

hi could you please refer to these as its exactly what you need:

hide list for users or groups using javascript:

http://sharepointnadeem.blogspot.co.uk/2011/09/hide-sharepoint-list-field-based-on.html

Customizing user access to a SharePoint list or library:

http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint-server-help/customizing-user-access-to-a-sharepoint-list-or-library-HA010253649.aspx

also somthing similar:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7761289/sharepoint-2007-2010-hiding-list-or-library-items-i-e-rows

and

Show\Hide list items from specific users or group in SharePoint

> 1. Create two views, one with all the all the list data that you want to show to your readers in the company.   2 Next create another view
>      that will conatin other columns which you want to show it to a
>      specific users.
> 2. Create a new column "Privileged User" People and Group and with "Allow Multiple Selections" is Yes and "Allow Selection of" -> "People
>      Only"
> 3. Next Filetr your second view where the "Privileged User" as [Me]
> 4. Lastly, Edit the list in a datasheet view and copy and paste the user or group that you want to give access to in the Privileged User
>      column.

http://spdailytips.blogspot.co.uk/2011/09/showhide-list-items-from-specific-users.html

hope it helps :)

Comment: @almostSharepointMaster... thanks for your info.. but all the above links are saying how to hide list fields. But I want to know how to hide entire list from an user.

Answer (score 0):

1- Create a new page, give permissions to users that you want to see the list.
2- Add "List view webpart", you will find it with the same name as the list.
3- Configurate the view.
in this case you can control the permission of the page, because sharepoint don't allow to hide users from creating views.

/KD