# Creating different list views for each user group in SharePoint 2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-designer, 2013, out-of-the-box

I have a list that contains sensitive information.
The full control user group needs visibility of all columns but the read group are only allowed to view a limited number of columns.
I cannot see how I can do this out of the box in SharePoint 2013.
I have access to SharePoint Designer if that helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Out of the box approach will be to add 2 views on the page with different set of columns and set the audience targeting property of the web part to the particular user group.

When you edit a web part; in "Advanced" tab you will get "Target Audiences" option.

Comment: I do not see this option. Are you sure it is even in SharePoint 2013?

Comment: Also how does this stop people just clicking on the list itself to see the data. If I understand you correctly the filtering is done in the web part. This can be circumvented by just viewing the list.

Comment: Yes, this option is present in SP2013. When you add web part on a page, edit the web part and in "Advanced" tab you will get this option.

Comment: Also check
http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/44609/how-to-hide-specific-list-from-user-or-a-group

Comment: The option is not in the advanced tab. What level of access do you need to see it? I see Allow minimise/close/hide/zone changes/connections/editing in personal view/title url/description/help url/ and a few others but not Target Audiences.

Comment: Your user profile service must be up and running for this. No special accesses are needed.

Answer (score 1):

In order to get this option in the Advanced tab, you need to enable the Target Audiences in your app. Go to the app's settings, and under General Settings, you will see an option called " Audience targeting settings  ". If you click on that, you will be able to enable it, and it will show under the Advanced Tab when you edit the App Part.